# Indexed types and template literals - prefix every key

Tags: typescript

Take type A. Create type B by prefixing every key in A with `x` using Typescript's latest Template Literal Types:

```
type A = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
};

// Create this automatically.
type Prefixed = {
  xa: string;
  xb: string;
};
```

How do I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type B = { [T in keyof typeof A as `x${T}`]: A[T] }
```

Some helpers like `Capitalize<T>` exist as well.

Comment: Please consider linking to the [documentation for key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) and possibly also the [documentation for template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types)